# Como heredar desde una clase Object en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, herencia

Estoy heredando desde una clase Object, mi clase clsXArrayDb para manejar una Matriz(,); pero cuando hago lo siguiente

```
public objPubXArray as clsXArrayDb(,)
objPubXArray (0,0) = 1
```

Me sale un error que dice que "no se puede convertir de entero a clsXArrayDb".

Mi clase esta heredando asi

```
Public Class clsXArrayDB
Inherits Object
Private vIntRow As Integer
Private vIntColumn As Integer
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New
    Me.vIntRow = 0
    Me.vIntColumn = 0


End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal pvIntRow As Integer, ByVal pvIntColumn As Integer)
    Me.vIntRow = pvIntRow
    Me.vIntColumn = pvIntColumn
End Sub
End Class
```

Debo tener algo en cuenta?

Comment: Porque heredas de object, si todo hereda de object por defecto? y tu clase, no es un array.. asi como definiste es una matriz de objetos de tipo clsXArrayDb... el array esta adentro de la clase...

Comment: de paso.. mira [ask].. y usa solo las etiquetas que correspondan a tu pregunta... ni c# ni vb tienen nada que hacer aca...

Comment: Lo heredo de un Object por que quiero encapsularlo en una clase, para solo manejar esa clase y no un Object, la clase le puse ese nombre porque inicialmente iba a heredar de una clase Array, pero esta al ser una clase Base, no es heredable, perdón por no cambiarla, pero ando haciendo pruebas.

Comment: y si lo que necesito es que mi clase clsXArrayDb, sea una matriz de dimension (nxn), pero no se como implementarla.

Comment: Tenes claro que en .net, toda clase hereda de object no? salvo que me este confundiendo y en vb.net funcione distinto... Igual, no entiendo que tratas de hacer.. pero vos entendiste lo que te marque como error?

Comment: tu clase, es solo un objeto que tiene dos posiciones (ponele).. le faltaria un valor.. y despues te faltaria otra clase que hiciera una matriz de objetos de esta clase (ponele).. no me queda claro que queres de resultado...

Comment: gbianchi, lo que quiero es que pueda crear una variable de tipo clsXArrayDB(,) de 2 posiciones y que luego a esta se le puedan agregar valores en cada posición, mejor dicho que funcione como una matriz(nxn).

Comment: Ok... entonces no hay nada de lo que hayas hecho que este correcto.. para empezar, falta el valor... tu clase, solo toma una columna y una fila... deberia tener una matriz (cuac) adentro que guarde filas y columnas... o deberias tener un objeto matriz de este tipo de objetos... cosa que no estas haciendo tampoco... supongo que es alguna clase de ejercicio de clase no?

Comment: Si, asi es, solo que no se hacerlo o la idea que tenia no funciona bien

Comment: Bueno.. ahora, para no resolver yo tu ejercicio (que ni se como es)... replantea la idea... tu clase, contiene un valor.. una fila y una columna... y despues tendras un array de objetos de este tipo... No es lo mejor... pero al parecer es lo que queres.. y no heredes de objeto, de eso ya heredas siempre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de esta forma, teniendo en cuenta tu comentario @gbianchi

```
Default Public Property Index(ByVal pvIntRow As Integer, ByVal pvIntColumn As 
Integer) As Object
    Get
        Return vArray(pvIntRow, pvIntColumn) '(vIntRow, vIntColumn)
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        vArray(pvIntRow, pvIntColumn) = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Value As Array
    Get
        Return vArray
    End Get
    Set(value As Array)

        vArray = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Esto me permite que mi clase se comporte como un Object y tenga por dentro una propiedad de tipo Array, para que toda variable de tipo clsXArrayDb se comporte como una Matriz nxn, quedando encapsulado dentro de mi clase.

ya lo puedo declarar de esta forma

```
Public pubXArrObj As New clsXArrayDB
```

y mas abajo lo redimensiono a lo que se requiere

Gracias @gbianchi.